# working with the value from slider/entry in c#

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, binding

So I am currently writing on a Xamarin.Forms program that collects data from user inputs but I just can't figure out how to work with the data my Entry/Slider combination provides/how to extract it.

Here is what my slider linked to the entryfield looks like:

```
<Entry
     Text="{Binding Path=Value}"
     FontSize="18"
     x:Name="label"
     BindingContext="{x:Reference Name=Slider}" />

<Slider 
     BindingContext="{Binding Score}"
     x:Name="Slider"
     Maximum="100"
     VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
```

In the ViewModel the code looks like this:

```
private int score;

public int Score
{
    get => score;
    set => SetProperty(ref score, value);
}

FinalScore = score
```

This is then being passed to a (working) sqlite-Database.

I desperately need help since I have been trying to solve this issue for 2-3 days and nothing works. In the DB the FinalScore is always 0?!

Comment: "solve this issue" - you haven't explained what the problem is.  The only specific problem you mention is "FinalScore is always 0" in the DB, but the code you posted has nothing to do with the DB.

Comment: Have you put a breakpoint on Score "set" line, to see if it is called, and with what value? And a breakpoint on `FinalScore = score`, to see if score is what you expect? Bottom line: find the line of code where something isn't what you expect. Then someone can help figure out why.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve yes, that helped a lot, thank you, so I think that the Binding is the problem as my EntryBox is linked to the Slider and therefore can't be bound again. That's why I wanted to bind the slider. I have never worked with it so I don't know how..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your efforts to help me but as I stated in my comment to @Jessie Zhang -MSFT, the problem was with the Binding as I used `BindingContext` to extract the slider's value where I should have used `Value="{Binding Score}"`.

I know, my question wasn't asked good enough (shouldn't have asked for the help with a DB as i didn't need any) for you guys to be able to help me. That is due to my lack of expirience in C# and development generally. Therefore I wanted to thank you @Jessie Zhang and @ToolmakerSteve for your help with breakpoints etc.

Here is my new, working, code for everyone opposing a similar problem (I also switched to using `string` instead of `int` due to later work with the output-number which required me to get it as a `string`):

The slider-entrybox-combination:

```
<Entry
         Text="{Binding Path=Value}"
         FontSize="18"
         x:Name="label"
         BindingContext="{x:Reference Name=Slider}"/>
<Slider 
         Value="{Binding Score}"
         x:Name="Slider"
         Maximum="100"
         VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
```

The ViewModel:

```
private string score;    

public string Score
{
    get => score;
    set => SetProperty(ref score, value);
}
```

(Also ViewModel) The SaveFunction for the Database:

```
    private async void OnSave()
    {
        DatabaseEntry newEntry = new DatabaseEntry()
        {
            FinalScore = Score
        };

        await App.Database.SaveDatabaseEntry(newEntry);

        // This will pop the current page off the navigation stack
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("..");
    }
```

The Entry-Class as another user was curious about that:

```
using System;
using SQLite;

namespace MyProject.Models
{
    [Table("DatabaseEntry")]
    public class DatabaseEntry : IComparable
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement, Column("ID")]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Column("FinalScore")]
        public string FinalScore { get; set; }

        public int CompareTo(object other)
        {
            var otherEntry = (DatabaseEntry)other;
            if (otherEntry == null)
                return 1;

            if (ID == otherEntry.ID)
                return 0;

            return 1;
        }

    }
}
```

And finnaly the SQLite-Database itself:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using SQLite;
using MyProject.Models;

namespace MyProject.Services
{
    public class Database
    {
        readonly SQLiteAsyncConnection database;

        public Database(string dbPath)
        {
            database = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbPath);
            database.CreateTableAsync<DatabaseEntry>().Wait();
        }

        public Task<List<DatabaseEntry>> GetDatabaseEntries()
        {
            return database.Table<DatabaseEntry>().ToListAsync();
        }

        public Task<DatabaseEntry> GetDatanaseEntry(int id)
        {
            return database.Table<DatabaseEntry>().Where(i => i.ID == id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        }

        public Task<int> SaveDatabaseEntry(DatabaseEntry entry)
        {
            if (entry.ID != 0)
            {
                return database.UpdateAsync(entry);
            }
            else
            {
                return database.InsertAsync(entry);
            }
        }

        public Task<int> DeleteDatabaseEntry(DatabaseEntry entry)
        {
            return database.DeleteAsync(entry);
        }
    }
}
```

I posted this code so that anyone in need could get help (especially with the slider and entry combination)

Have a great day!

Comment: Excellent! Good job sticking to it until you understood how to use the different concepts.

Comment: Thanks! This is actually my first project in C# and Xamarin.Forms so I am still collecting expirience as I have only worked with JS and Python so this is confusing for me to get into but im sure i'll make my way :)

Answer (score 0):

> In the DB the FinalScore is always 0?!

That's because the `FinalScore`  only get the initial value of `score` .

Then, every time `Score` is updated, you don't update `FinalScore`.

You can refer to the following code:

```
    private int score;

    public int Score
    {
        get => score;
        set {

           SetProperty(ref score, value);

            //update the valueof `FinalScore ` once updating `Score`
            FinalScore = score;

        }
    }
```

**Note:**

You also need to validate the input value to ensure that it can be converted to a value acceptable for the slider.

Comment: Hi @T I M O N, may I know if you have got any chance to check my answer? I am glad to help if you have any other questions.

Comment: Yes, thank you but I think the problem is with the Binding. I used breakpoints to check the value at different states but it's already "null" in the ViewModel.

Comment: I think I'll have to rework the Slider-Entry-combination because I don't think I can simply use a Binding in the Slider to extract it's value